# Do Firebase Dynamic Links have a usage quota?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm implementing a Firebase Dynamic Link, but have a concern regarding traffic.  Is there a quota on usage?  For example, if you exceed your quota on many of the Google Cloud API products, you will receive an error. (e.g. error code 429)

Do firebase Dynamic Links have a usage quota?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Answer (score 6):

No, Dynamic Link usage is free and unlimited in volume.  The only limits are around the [rate at which they can be served](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#next_steps):

> Requests are limited to 50 queries per second and 100,000 queries per day. If exceeded, then the response will return HTTP error code 429. To request for more quota, fill out this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfPS2BfT5x9nwYrnQIrqu8Pzgcy2XF45Uv8ZsqBoL4RFEoQNg/viewform).

Comment: Do you know of a Google or Firebase page which says this explicitly?

Comment: What does "be served" mean?

Comment: Dealing an expected response.

Comment: What happens when the query limit is exceeded?  Is it s a hard bounce or a throttle? What is the user experience? @DougStevenson

Comment: I recently filed out the form for a project, but haven't heard back yet.  How long does it usually take?  @DougStevenson

Comment: @BruceSeymour Did you ever get a response back? When you go over your limit, you will get back a 429 HTTP status code response with information about the limit included in the body.

Comment: No, I never heard back from Google Support which I why I use another service now.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are limited to 5 requests/IP address/second, and 200,000 requests/day. If exceeded, then the response will return HTTP error code 429. To request for more quota, fill out this form: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/fdl/quotas